# I'm interviewing for a j2EE position using the Spring Framework; help me brush up

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I'll be interviewing for a J2EE job using the Spring Framework next week. I've used Spring in my last couple of positions, but I probably want to brush up on it.

What should I keep in mind, and what web sites should look at, to brush up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think excellent way to brush up on spring framework skills are to cover concepts given in DZone's RefCards. They are concise PDF format documents.

- [Spring Configuration RefCardz](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/spring-configuration)
- [Spring Annotations RefCards](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/spring-annotations)
- [Spring and Flex Configuration](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/flex-spring-integration)

Hope this helps!!

Peacefulfire

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't ask about the framework in itself, but in which cases would be convenient to apply its features, like when to use LoadTimeWeaving aspects or whether to DI domain objects or not.

I see spring as a tool for solving problems, and I'd like the other person to tell me how would he apply it, when, and most important in which case he *wouldn't* use it.

Comment: Excellent answer. It's the concepts that matter, not the specific tool.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at some of the newer projects and updates that SpringSource is working on.

- Spring 3.0 (Key new features are RESTful support on top of MVC, and new expression language)
- Spring dm Server (OSGi-based server)
- Spring tc Server (preconfigured tomcat)
- Spring AMS (centralised management and monitoring of assets)
- Spring Security (Now supports expression language which makes for much richer declarative security demarcations)
- Spring Integration (Implements a number of the patterns from Enterprise Integration Patterns: gateways, splitters, aggregators, transformers, etc..)
- Grails

Just announced at SpringOne:

- Roo - a build assistant with command-line options similar to grails for creating domain classes, controllers, and views, but for vanilla java instead of groovy.
- SpringSource Tool Suite is now free!